# MySQL error on remote server

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using Openshift and have `mysql-python` installed on my local machine and remotely

The code that's causing the error is the following line:

```
cursor.execute("insert into Quotes (A_ID, F_ID, C_ID, Quote, Quote_Time, Rating, Votes) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (aid, fid, cid, quote, 120, 0, 0))
```

I get the following error remotely but not locally:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), ('2',), ('2',), 'Do not take me for a conjurer of tricks', 120, 0, 0)' at line 1")
```

I'm pretty sure the same version of `mysql` are on both as I just ran `pip install mysql-python` remotely and locally

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey Greg, unless I'm reading this wrong, you have seven %s variables, but six values going in.

Comment: what is in `aid`?

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. I count 7 values. `aid` is just a foreign key as are some of the other fields

Comment: According to the error, the first three values you are passing into `cursor.execute` are tuples and not scalars.  I would do a `print` before the `cursor.execute` so that you could ensure that they are scalar.

Comment: Either it's breaking cause [you have the quote wrong](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lKaw5SjeHx0) or the problem is what 2ps said.

Comment: 2ps solved the problem thank you so much